# Add various input fields together using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have several text fields

```
<input class="add" type="text">
<input class="add" type="text">
<input class="add" type="text">
<input class="add" type="text">
<p id="total"></p>
```

The values in each field are added dynamically by a PHP script when the page is loaded but the user has the option to edit them. I have been trying to figure out a way to add up all the values using javascript and output them into the #total p tag. I have found a few scripts arround and tried writing one myself but it didnt seam to work.

The best I found looked like this....

```
function addAll() {
  var sum = ""

  var values = $('.add').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  $('#total').text(sum);
}
$('.add').keyup(displayTotal);
```

But that didn't output anything

Am I doing anything seriously wrong?

Cheers

Comment: You define a function called `addAll()` but your keyup event is calling a function called `displayTotal()` which we don't see here. Maybe you just used the wrong function reference?

Comment: @paiCode - Rather `$(this).val()` than `this.val()` - note `this` in callback is pure `HTMLElement` not `jQuery` items set.  `$(this).val()` which is short hand for `$(this).attr('value')` ie exactly `this.value`

Comment: @paiCode: No, please don't. ;) `this` inside the callback references the element itself, it doesn't create a new jQuery object for each element.

Comment: @abuduba sorry, I meant $(this). Just a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's numbers you're adding then this should work:

```
function addAll() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.add').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  $('#total').html(sum);
}
$('.add').keyup(addAll);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DULYW/2/)

If you want this to work on page load then add a call to `addAll` in the `.ready()` function. Here's the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  addAll();
  $('.add').keyup(addAll);  
})

function addAll() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.add').each(function(){
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });

  $('#total').html(sum);
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution on this test page

http://www.tutorplanner.com/untitled.html

but still no joy... any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I relaised what I was doing wrong :) 

Is there anyway to make this work from page load? At the moment it only works once I have edited one of the values

Comment: That no only works when the page loads but not when the values are edited - http://www.tutorplanner.com/untitled.html - any idea?

Answer (score 1):

var sum = 0;

sum += isNaN($(this).val()) || $.trim($(this).val()) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.val());

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.add').keyup( function(){
  var sum = 0;

   $('.add').each(function(){
         sum +=  this.value && (this.value|0) && parseFloat( this.value ) || 0;
    });
   $('#total').text(sum);

});
```